# Morphia. How to clone query with different collection(kind)

Tags: mongodb, morphia

The problem is about searching by query in different collections.

There is a method in `AdvancedDatastore` interface:

```
<T> Query<T> createQuery(String kind, Class<T> clazz, DBObject q);
```

But its only create query  with given baseQuery and I need full clone of Query but with different DBCollection field.
Any suggestions?

Here is my method to convert query:

```
public Query<Vacancy> convertQuery(Query<T> query) {
        QueryImpl<T> queryImpl = (QueryImpl<T>) query;
        DBObject dbO = queryImpl.getQueryObject();
        Query<T> our_query = ((AdvancedDatastore)this.getDatastore()).createQuery("AnotherCollectionName", T.class, dbO);           
        return our_query;
    }
```

**Update**

Works fine with reflection, but I dont like this dirty way because of perfomance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a good solution for now. You cannot change the underlying collection/kind once a query is created -- it is immutable.

If you want this functionality one would need to implement a deep clone operator for the Query/QueryImpl or request that be done in [morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/issues).